# Display comma list in gridview from child entity

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, gridview

I need to display a N item list from an child entity class in a cell of a grid.

I have a complex entity (from EF6) such as

```
public partial class DEALER
{
    public DEALER()
    {
        this.DEALER_MODEL = new HashSet<DEALER_MODEL>();
    }

    public int DEALER_KY { get; set; }
    public string DEALER_NAME { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<DEALER_MODEL> DEALER_MODEL { get; set; }
}

public partial class DEALER_MODEL
{   
    public int DEALER_MODEL_KY { get; set; }
    public string MODEL_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

I have a GridView that I want to display the list of models as a comma string.

```
<asp:GridView ID="DealerGrid" runat="server" CssClass="tx-form"
   EnableViewState="false" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="true"
   PageSize="25" AllowSorting="true" GridLines="None" CellPadding="2" 
   CellSpacing="0" OnSorting="DealerGrid_Sorting"
   OnPageIndexChanging="DealerGrid_PageIndexChanging">
   <HeaderStyle BackColor="#F4F1CD" ForeColor="#003359" Wrap="true" />
      <RowStyle BackColor="#FBF9EB" />
      <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E4DEB0" />
      <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" />
      <Columns>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="DEALER_KY" Visible="false" />
         <asp:HyperLinkField DataTextField="DEALER_NAME"
            SortExpression="DEALER_NAME"
            DataNavigateUrlFields="DEALER_KY"
            DataNavigateUrlFormatString="~\dealer.aspx?dealerkey={0}"
            HeaderText="Dealer Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left"
            HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"
            ItemStyle-Width="10%" ItemStyle-Wrap="false"/>
         <asp:BoundField DataField="DEALER_MODEL" HeaderText="Model"
            HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" 
            HeaderStyle-VerticalAlign="Top"/>
   </Columns>
```

I would like to display something like:

Joes Auto  | Acura, Century, LaCross

```
        -or -
```

Joes Auto  | Acura
                  Century
                  LaCross

I have tried a template field/eval and couldn't get it working.

I am new at asp.net and grids so be gentle. ;)

I cannot modify my classes since it is auto-generated by EF.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was actually pretty easy. I created a partial class (thus overloading the original class) and added the property.

```
public partial class DEALER
{
    public string ModelList { 
        get 
        {
            if (MODEL_NAME != null)
            {
                return string.Join(",", DEALER_MODEL.Select(i => i.MODEL_NAME.ToString()).ToArray());
            }
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get comma separated string with using `string.Join` method like this:

```
DealerGrid.DataSource =
    (from d in db.Dealers
     select new
     {
         DEALER_KY = d.DEALER_KY,
         DEALER_NAME = d.DEALER_NAME,
         DEALER_MODEL = string.Join(", ", d.DEALER_MODEL.Select(m => m.MODEL_NAME).ToArray())
     });
DealerGrid.DataBind();
```

Comment: I like this answer too but a little more work to up keep if the data model changes but basically came up with the same idea.